# Shape of an isochoric curve in T-s and h-s diagrams during phase changes

Tags: thermodynamics, phase-transition

In the pV diagram an isochoric curve is, of course, a vertical line whereas in the T-s diagram it has the form:

$$T(s)=T_0 \space e^{\frac{s-s_0}{c_V}}\tag1$$

so it is an exponential function (steeper than an isobare).  This equation holds for an ideal gas, in a Ts diagram (no phase changes considered).

Since $h=u+pv$ I presume that all the function in the h-s diagram would be a scaled versions of the ones in the T-s diagram, although I am not sure of this fact.

But my main question is how would an isochoric process be plotted in T-s and h-s diagrams during phase changes. Let's presume that we are looking at process from liquid to steam for water.

Also, is it possible to provide a closed form solution as I did in $(1)$?

**Appendix**:

Here are the pictures from my book; Galović, Termodinamika 1.

[image]

The isochoric curve, $v=const.$, looks like an exponential function in the vapor phase of both T-s and h-s diagrams, as predicted by $(1)$. Vapor behaves more and more like an ideal gas as temperature rises.

But my question is how can we describe its shape during phase change, when it is in the heterogenous phase of both liquid and vapor (i.e. inside the bell curves).

There, it looks like it is curving downwards, so it doesn't have exponential properties as it does outside that region.

With what kind of function would we describe it there?

Comment: Your formula (1) is not a general relation. It holds only for a perfect gas (perfect gases have no phase transitions).

Comment: Thanks, of course. I will edit it.

Comment: Have you. examined any T-S and H-S diagrams in textbooks?

Comment: @ChetMiller Hi, I have and I have made an edit with the pictures from my textbook, but in it I found no explanation as to why that is the shape of the function.

Comment: The graphs you provided include a liquid region in which the average specific volume over liquid and vapor is shown.

Comment: @ChetMiller so that means that the analytic form doesn't exist and it is plotted using experimental values in that region?

Comment: Kind of, although most of the results in the figures are calculated from more general property relationships.